# Unauthorized error when associating a test to MTM

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests

I want to associate my codedui test to a test in MTM , when I click İt ask for credentials but I get this error

```
    The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I am sure my credentials are correct because I connect to tf server through Vsiual Sydioı and I cna do check-in, however I can not use associate feature, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is a TFS rights issue. Please ask your TFS admin to give you full rights, that should fix the problem.

Comment: Thats not the case, I have been told I have rights.